# Teamcity - How to resolve Maven dependencies of other modules without using an artifact repository?

Tags: maven, teamcity

I have two Maven modules A and B where Module B depends on module A, i.e, I've added module A's JAR as a dependency in module B's pom.xml. Building of these modules in my local PC doesn't have any issue.

The problem arises when I try to build these two modules using my organization's Teamcity server (means I can't edit any other Teamcity settings). Teamcity builds module A without any issue. But while building module B, the build fails complaining it couldn't resolve module A, i.e, it is not found in the artifact repository.

Is there any way I can refer to module A while building module B inside Teamcity (without using an artifact repository (Nexus/Artifactory) to store module A's artifacts)?

Comment: In theory you can do an install on a local cache on the TeamCity machine (if build is running always on the same node)..and run the second project afterwards but that's in the end not a real solution only a hack...

Comment: Artifact dependencies doesn't work for you? Did you set "Run build on the same agent" flag in snapshot dependencies?

Comment: @Peska Thanks. Using "Run build on the same agent" worked. I used a maven install for module A and on the same agent, I built module B which worked.